# Is UniObjects supported in UniData 8.x?

Tags: unidata, uniobjects

We integrated with UniData in 2013 using UniObjects for .net and we tested against UniData 7.3. We now have a client on a newer versions of UniData (8.1) and we are having new problems with the integration.

I dug through the documentation on RocketSoftware's website and found the UniObject documents were no longer listed under the documentation for UniData 8.1 and 8.2. I also couldn't find any recent threads via search engine around UniObjects.

"UniObjects for .net Developer's Guide" is listed here:
https://www.rocketsoftware.com/products/rocket-u2/UniData-v7.2

Not listed here:
https://www.rocketsoftware.com/products/rocket-u2/rocket-unidata-v821-technical-documentation

I'm not sure if the documentation just moved and I am overlooking it on the site or if it went away entirely. My suspicion is that it's not supported anymore or won't be supported soon.

Does anyone know definitively that UniObjects is supported or not supported in 8.x versions of UniData?

Any insight around this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely supported.  I work with an application that uses Uniobjects for integration extensively and it works the same as ever with 8.1 on Linux.  The documentation is kind of a mess and keeps moving around, but the functionality is definitely still there.

There were security/encryption changes a few years ago, so the parameters around that are a good place to start looking.  There's also a debug flag to check what's happenning - serverdebug.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/u2-users/okE3-TL_mvE was a recent thread on u2users group, it may be worth asking in that forum to get more responses too.  It's a friendly bunch.

Comment: Great answer! I just wanted to add that Rocket's new connection library, U2 .NET Toolkit, is essentially a direct replacement for UniObjects if you stick to the "Native" portion of the library. After switching over to it, our application, which does a lot of UniDynArray manipulations, performed at least 50% faster.